# Automatic ordering of table with Extension method triggering before Input field exits

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, blazor

Basically I have a custom table that iterates through a list of objects, although I call an extension method that returns a dictionary from that list depending on some value on the child objects.

For example:

List returns Dictionary<List,bool>

```html
foreach(var dic in list.ExtensionMethod()) {
    <InputDate etc...>
    <InputText etc...>
}
```

Problem is, the extension method is happening so quick on every UI change, its rapidly reorganizing my table every time a user inputs data, and it even happens before a user is done typing in input fields

Comment: What's in the extension method and how are you binding the inputs?

Comment: The extension method is reordering the list, and creating a dictionary to loop through. The inputs are binded with bind-Value, which may be the problem. Let me try @bind

Comment: The parent will render every time a field is updated, and thus your loop will be run.  You almost certainly have some sort of feedback look.

Comment: Yes i know the loop will be rerun, i have no problem with that, but it is rerun before the user is even finished entering the data in the input field sometimes

Comment: What event are you binding to on the input field?  Which field?

Comment: At the moment it's almost all guesswork as you've provided very little code.

Comment: I'm binding on the same field that the extension method is altering, those are dates, input numbers, etc. The @bind-Value for blazor InputDate, InputNumber, InputText components is the only binding being used

Comment: Your blazor is webassmbly or server?  If possible, could you please provide an example with us to check and we could give you a solution or workaround?

Comment: I found a workaround,

Comment: I used a ValueChange event handler on the place where the binding was happening to instead manually call the extension method, call state has changed, and use js interop to select the input box that has been shifted in the associated table to a different row based on the ordering logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a ValueChange event handler on the place where the binding was happening to instead manually call the extension method, call state has changed, and use js interop to select the input box that has been shifted in the associated table to a different row based on the ordering logic.